# How to print a 2D array of different index lengths?

Tags: java, arrays, printing, arraylist, automation

I currently have a 2D array which looks the equivalent of:

```
int[] my2Darray = {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {1}};
//the second dimensions can and do vary
```

I was wondering how I can print all elements of this array automatically.

My code to print currently looks like:

```
for(int t = 0; t < movieactorsbulk.size(); t++) {
       temparray = movieactorsbulk.get(t).split("\\s");
       movieactorsindiv[t] = new String[temparray.length];
        for(int v = 0; v < temparray.length; v++) {
            movieactorsindiv[t][v] = temparray[v];
        }
    }
```

movieactorsbulk contains: [a00011974 a00011975, a00011975 a00011974, a77777777]

So I am trying to separate the indexes of the ArrayList movieactorsbulk) and put it into a 2D array (movieactorsindiv) then print everything no matter the size.

Right now I know my problem is that on the last go around the code splits "a77777777" and puts it into movieactorsindiv[2][0] but when I try to print based on temparray.length it only prints the first indexes as temparray[] only contains "a77777777" at that point.  How can I print all indexes of movieactorsindiv ([0][0] through to [x][y]; where x and y can be any number)?

Any help would be appreciated.  Sorry if the question isn't easy to understand. :S

Answer (score 2):

Try using this skeleton of a traversal:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
        // print matrix[i][j]
    }
}
```

It takes into consideration the case where each row's columns can be of different length. It works for 2-D matrices of any height and width (even of varying widths), and it'll be easy to adapt for your problem in particular.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help.  What you proposed makes a lot more sense to me than what I was trying to do. :)

Comment: @SomeoneSomeone I'm glad to hear that! if this answer was helpful for you, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking on the check mark to its left ;)